# Remove handheld footer menu links Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, mobile, woocommerce, cart, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to remove the **search** link from the Woocommerce handheld footer menu which appears when using a mobile device.

I have tried following the official Woocommerce guide here on [Customizing links in the handheld footer menu](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/customize-the-links-in-the-handheld-footer-bar/), but the code doesn't change the behaviour. I have already tried clearing cache, cookies & inprivate browsing to test. Any suggestions why this isn't changing?

[image]

**Code:**

```
add_filter( 'storefront_handheld_footer_bar_links', 'jk_remove_handheld_footer_links' );
function jk_remove_handheld_footer_links( $links ) {

    unset( $links['search'] );

    return $links;
}
```

Comment: what are the links if you do var_dump($links) what are the keys that come back, it could be that is custom-search or just a variation of search?

Comment: @OrlandoP. - Sorry, not sure what you mean...can you explain in more detail please?

Comment: Sure. $links is an array and your unsetting a value of it using its key which is search. In your function if you add var_dump($links); you will get the keys and values within that array than we can see what the right key will be to remove that search link.

Comment: Okay, figured it out! Because I was modifying the HTML of the `handheld_footer` that was taking precedence of the PHP function. Once I changed the HTML, the PHP function worked...thanks for your help in debugging!

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code will work. However, if you are modifying the HTML of `storefront_handheld_footer_bar_links` anywhere else in your Woocommerce site, this will override and take precedence of the PHP function.

Bear this in mind when trying to modify the above function.

Thanks @Orlando P. for help in debugging.